# How to getimagesize() after file_get_contents()?

Tags: php

Unless I am mistaken, doing it the obvious way would download the file twice.

```
$image = file_get_contents($location);
$checkImage = getimagesize($location);
```

I was wondering how I could do it without downloading twice. Placing `$image` inside `get_image_size()` doesn't work so I am not sure what to do. I found my tmp folder but when I ran the page to test I didn't see anything show up there so I'm not sure where to go with this. if I need to specify the actual location of `$image` (I think that is what I need to do) I am not sure how to find that.

Answer (score 10):

```
$binary_data = file_get_contents($location);
$im = imagecreatefromstring($binary_data);
$width = imagesx($im);
$height = imagesy($im);
```

Comment: Can you get the file type this way? I'm actually using getimagesize to verify that it is an image and make sure it gets the right file extension after giving it a random name.

Comment: Then you have to cache the file into a temp path , and then do your actions

Comment: That is what I was asking about.

Answer (score 5):

```
    $image = file_get_contents($location);
    $checkImage = getimagesizefromstring($image);
```